# Include Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 to installer with InstallShield Limited Edition

Tags: ms-access, installshield-le, database-engine

How can I include Microsoft Office Access database engine 2007 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734) to installer with InstallShield Limited Edition?

Answer (score 0):

I not used installsheild, but typically such installers allow you to include a package and “chain” to that msi as part of the install. You can add a few command line options to the msi to have the install show “just” a progress bar or even command lines options for a silent install.

So you would not attempt to re-create the msi install for the runtime but you certainly could include the package and chain + install that application as part of your overall installer scripts. I do the above with the Inno installer and thus include the runtime as part of the package.

Comment: The problem is in Installshield, although they allow you add prerequisite software, but for the Limited Edition, you can only select what already in their list, you can not create your own prerequisite.

Comment: I found a work around by downloading the trial pro version, and create my own prerequisite from that.